# Eloquent relationship through 2 models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have Post model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'category_id',
        'user_id',
        'img',
        'title',
        'content',
    ];

    public function user(){
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function category(){
      return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function comments(){
      return $this->hasMany(Comment::class)->where('parent_id', '0');
    }
}
```

Comments model:

```
class Comment extends Model
{

use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'post_id',
        'user_id',
        'parent_id',
        'content',
        // 'img'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

     public function replies()
     {
      return $this->hasMany(Comment::class,'parent_id');
    }
  }
```

Can I use the replies function via the post model?
For example:

```
@foreach($comments->comments->replies->sortByDesc('id') as $comment)
@endforeach
```

I am just trying to add replies to comments.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="blog-comment">
                        <hr/>
                <ul class="comments">
                <li class="clearfix">
                @foreach($post as $comments)
                  @foreach($comments->comments->sortByDesc('id') as $comment)
                  <img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" class="avatar">
                  <div class="post-comments">
                      <p class="meta d-flex justify-content-between"><a href="#">{{ $comments->user->name }}</a><span>{{ $comments->user->created_at }}</span></p>
                      <p>
                          {{ $comment->content }}
                      </p>
                  </div>
                <form action="{{ route('comment.store') }}" method="POST" class="w-100">
                  @csrf
                  <div class="replyform d-flex mb-3">
                      <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{ $comments->id }}">
                      <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="{{ $comment->id }}">
                      <input class="d-block ml-auto w-50 align-top" type="text" name="content" required>
                      <button type="submit" class="offset replysub fas fa-paper-plane ml-1"></button>
                  </div>
                </form>
                    @endforeach
                  @endforeach
                  @foreach($comments->comments->replies->sortByDesc('id') as $comment)
                    @if($comment->parent_id !== 0)
                  <ul class="comments">
                      <li class="clearfix">
                          <img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_3.jpg" class="avatar">
                          <div class="post-comments">
                              <p class="meta">Dec 20, 2014 <a href="#">JohnDoe</a> says : <i class="pull-right"><a href="#"><small>Reply</small></a></i></p>
                              <p>
                                  {{ $comment->content }}
                              </p>
                          </div>
                          <input class="replyform d-block ml-auto mb-3 w-50" type="text" name="" value="">
                      </li>
                  </ul>
                    @endif
                  @endforeach
                </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Of course, I can take and pass one more variable to the template, but I heard that you shouldn't do this, it overloads the controller. Therefore, I try to do it through an eloquent relationship.

P.S. Or is there a way to do it in the post model? Like:

```
public function replies(){
      return $this->hasMany(Comment::class)->where('parent_id', 'id(of parent comment)');
    }
```

Comment: did u try `comments->replies()` as a method and not as property?

Comment: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::replies does not exist.